# Setting the ticker speed

Tags: easeljs, createjs

I am new to the Easeljs library and I am trying to make a circle shape follow the mouse. The problem I am encountering is that the circle is placed at the cursor's position immediately, but I want it to move slowly towards the location of the cursor. I have already tried the follow code.

```
var stage, label, circle;

function init() {
stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");

var circle = new createjs.Shape();
circle.graphics.beginFill("red").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
circle.x = 100;
circle.y = 100;

stage.addChild(circle); 

stage.addEventListener("stagemousemove",function(evt) { 

    circle.x = evt.stageX;
    circle.y = evt.stageY;

    createjs.Ticker.on("tick", tick); //parameters?
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);

    stage.addChild(circle); 
    stage.update();
})

}

function tick(event, target_x, target_y) {
if(circle.x < target_x){
    circle.x = circle.x + 1;
}
if(circle.y < target_y){
    circle.y = circle.y + 1;
}
if(circle.x > target_x){
    circle.x = circle.x - 1;
}
if(circle.y > target_y){
    circle.y = circle.y - 1;
}

if(circle.y == target_y && circle.x == target_x){
    circle.x = target_x;
    circle.y = target_y;
}

stage.update(event); // important!!
}
```

But this code does not allow me to pass the target_x and the target_y variables to the tick function. Probably I am making some basic mistakes here, but I am not able to find the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pat4561

There are a few things that your code will need to achieve the animation effect that you are looking for.

What I would recommend would be to handle the animation interaction within the 'tick' event handler. Setting your shape's x/y position using stage.mouseX and stage.mouseY would be done within the tick.

For instance:

```
function tick(event) {
   //Position circle to mouse location immediately.
   circle.x = stage.mouseX;
   circle.y = stage.mouseY;
   ...
}
```

Don't try to pass parameters to the 'tick', since it's an event handler and it only expects an event as a parameter.

If you are looking for the shape to animate with an easing factor you would handle it like this:

```
function tick(event) {
  circle.x += (stage.mouseX - circle.x) / 6;
  circle.y += (stage.mouseY - circle.y) / 6;
  ...
}
```

Check out this working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sebastian_derossi/c60du1kx/) to see it in action

Also have a look at the many examples on the CreateJS [GitHub repo](https://github.com/CreateJS/)

There you'll find a ton of great working examples that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't cross that GitHub repo yet. Do you have any suggestions to make this animation a bit 'smoother' than it is in your fiddle? I read about animations and the it's frames per second on the createjs website. How could I apply this to your fiddle?

Comment: @Pat4561 I have updated the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/sebastian_derossi/c60du1kx/5/
I have updated to the latest version of EaselJS and have modified the ticker to use RAF which allows me to use the event's delta property so I can calculate the correct offset to apply. For more information check out the documentation here:  
http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Ticker.html#property_RAF